# Rangeのvertical配列は可能でしょうか。

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

現在、MonacaにてHTML5アプリを作ろうとしております。

CSS ComponetsのRangeについてなのですが、
http://ja.onsen.io/reference/css.html#range
スライダーをhorizontalだけでなく、verticalに配置することは可能なのでしょうか。

検索しても、Monacaの教則本を読んでも出てこなかったのでここで質問いたしました。
Onsen UIもしくはMonacaで解決する方法があればお教えいただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

Onsen UIについて詳しくありませんが、CSS3から`transform`が利用できるようになり、要素を自由に変形できるようになっていますので、`transform:rotate(90deg);`を指定すればverticalなスライダーを作成出来るかもしれません。

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);       
  -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

を追加してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速試してみます！

Comment: 解決しましたか？現状のステータスを更新していただけると助かります。よろしくお願いします。